# adding a list of vectors to a data.frame in R

Tags: r

How can I add a list of vectors to a preallocated data.frame such that the vectors form the rows of the data.frame?

eg.

```
ll<-list(c(1,2,3),c(2,3,4))
dd<-data.frame(matrix(nrow=10,ncol=3))
```

I need dd to look like

```
1 2 3
2 3 4
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's something odd about the question: You construct a dataframe with 10 rows, filled with NA values, but you need dd to have only 2 rows.

To answer your question first : sometimes the obvious isn't a bad solution.

```
ll<-list(c(1,2,3),c(2,3,4))
dd<-data.frame(matrix(nrow=5,ncol=3))

for(i in 1:length(ll)){
  dd[i,] <- ll[[i]]
}
dd
```

If you're staring at the ugly for-loop: this is a case where you could actually use a for-loop without problems. But this keeps dd having tons of NA values. If you want to get rid of them, you either initialize your dataframe as

```
dd<-data.frame(X1=numeric(0),X2=numeric(0),X3=numeric(0))
```

which gives you an empty dataframe, or you use complete.cases() to remove all NAs :

```
dd <- dd[complete.cases(dd),]
```

Answer (score 13):

```
do.call(rbind, ll)
```

To add to an existing data frame

```
rbind(dd, do.call(rbind, ll)
# OR 
do.call(rbind, c(ll, list(dd))
```

If you're doing this for many data frames, see `rbind.fill` in the `plyr` package for a much more efficient approach.