# Replacing data in .Rdata file

Tags: r, rdata

Is there a way I could replace the table in .Rdata file with another one? I can edit it with edit(x) command, but it would take an enormous amount of time to do this manually; besides, I haven't found a way to add rows to it.

Comment: If the data is "visible" in an R session which it would be if you can use `edit(x)`, then adding a row can be done with rbind (which has a data.frame method). See ?rbind .  And @nzcoops' comment about you needing to read more introductory material seems on point and you might consider searching SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6516116/appending-data-in-r http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3040352/merge-two-data-frames-together-that-have-the-same-variable-names-and-data-types  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665885/adding-a-list-of-vectors-to-a-data-frame-in-r

Answer (score 8):

I think you need to read a few 'intro to R' guides.

A .Rdata file is generally a saved session, and can have any number of 'things' saved in it, scalars, vectors, data.frames, lists, functions etc etc. I assume you have a data file that has been read into R into a data.frame and that is saved within a .Rdata file. You can load the .Rdata file with `load("....Rdata")` then you can 'replace' your table (a data frame), by loading another one over top, if that's what you want to do, so assuming it's called dat, `dat <- read.csv("new_data.csv", ...)`, and then save the session again, `save.image("....Rdata")`. I've assumed a lot of things there though...